# Max value of a column based on another max value.SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I want the max value of the load number and the max value of the load sequence number based on the max load number.

So let's say I have this:

```
id  | load_no |  load_seq_no |
----|---------|--------------|
1   |  200    |     1        |
----|---------|--------------|
2   |  200    |     2        |
----|---------|--------------|
3   |  200    |     3        |
----|---------|--------------|
4   |  300    |     1        |
----|---------|--------------|
5   |  300    |     2        |
----|---------|--------------|
6   |  300    |     2        |
----|---------|--------------|
```

and I want to select this

```
id  | load_no |  load_seq_no |
----|---------|--------------|
5   |  300    |     2        |
----|---------|--------------|
6   |  300    |     2        |
----|---------|--------------|
```

I want to get those results after full join a simplified version of my code is

{SELECT coalesce(table1.id, table2.id) AS id
    ,max(table1.load_no) OVER (PARTITION BY table1.id)
    ,table1.load_seq_no
    ,table2.load_seq_no
FROM table1
FULL JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id)
WHERE table1.load_no = 
    (SELECT max(table1.load_no)
        FROM table1)
    OR table2.load_no = 
    (SELECT max(table2.load_no)
        FROM table2)
    AND table1.load_seq_no = 
   (SELECT max(table1.load_seq_no)
        FROM table1)
    OR table2.load_seq_no = (SELECT max(table2.load_seq_no))}.

AND I ONLY get the max load_no NOT the max load_seq_no.

Comment: What did you try and what were undesired results or errors you encountered?

Comment: Do NOT post code in comments. Edit your post instead with attempted query. See link below post.

Answer (score 2):

you can try like below

```
  select * from t
  where load_no = (select max(load_no) from t)
  and load_seq_no = (select max(load_seq_no) from t
                            where load_no =(select max(load_no) from t)
                      )
```

Comment: max(load_no)=300 and max(load_seq_no)=3. It doesn't cover what he want.

Comment: That's it Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Could this fit your needs?

```
with x as(
select  max(load_seq_no) as mlsn, max(load_no) as mln  from tableName 
where load_no = (select max(load_no) from tableName )
) select * from tableName 
 join x on load_seq_no = mlsn and load_no = mln
```

Comment: you need to delete unnecessary and in last join.

Comment: No unfortunately i get 0 entries.

Comment: @sia there was i typo can You try again?